# Screen of a mobile phone inside something

Tags: rf, radio

As an image for a speech I want to be able to shield of the coverage of a mobile phone. I thought of putting it in something. So I grabbed the stewing pan made of cast iron from the kitchen. Unfortunately it did not change the coverage the slightest. Is it possible to shield of the mobile from communicating with the cell towers in a simple way with things I'm likely to have at home or can by in my grocery store?

I could buy a lot of tinfoil and wind a really thick cylinder. But I'm not sure that would work. Not when my stewing pan seemed to make no change at all.

Comment: You need a Faraday cage.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronics design.

Comment: Samuel: Ok thanks. Tried putting it in the microwave oven with just the wire for the headset sticking out. Didn't seem to be enough unfortunatly :-/

Comment: JYelton: Sorry, did not know where to ask. But I think I'm on my way solving this. A lot of tin foil probably would help.

Comment: Screen needs to be connected to the phone ground.

Comment: Leon: What? You mean that I should find my phones connector on the bottom that is ground?

Comment: I flagged myself and the moderators may tell if it should be closed or not. I think I'm on my solving this anyhow...

Comment: @Niclas I know it is a question that seems on-topic, but technically you are asking about fundamental properties of the electromagnetic spectrum, and how shielding and grounding relate to it. You *might* try on physics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stewing pan should work. But at first the cover must be metal as well. At second, the stewing pan must be grounded. Not necessary to the phone ground. Some other ground should work as well - some water pipes (metal) or other metal, grounded part should be enough. Connect the pan to the ground with short and thick piece of wire.

I am not very sure how you will check the signal level in such a screen, because it is not transparent.

Comment: I use two phone that has an ongoing call to each other. The first one is connected via a 3.5mm plug to a PA-system. The other one, which I place inside the stewing pan is connected to a bluetooth headset.

Comment: Ah, smart. But bluetooth also should be suppressed this way.

Comment: I know. Doesn't matter. I just want to show that the radio waves won't work because of the screen. That it is BOTH the bluetooth waves and the mobile signal is just a bonus :-)